# Can too many navigation properties be too much

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I have an entity:

```
public class User
{
   public int UserId{get;set;}
}
```

And another entity:

```
public class Role
{
   public int RoleId{get;set}
}
```

I want to model relation ship via EF Code First so I added:

**User.cs**

```
public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get;set;}
```

**Role.cs**

```
public virtual User User {get;set;}
```

This allow me to get user roles like:

```
context.Users.Roles.ToList();
```

But `User` is the main object in database. And it can have relations to 100 tables.

Is adding `ICollection<T>` and `User` object best practice or it is not always required (generally is there some rule of thumb for this)?

Sometimes I have feeling that I am creating too large objects and I wonder does this have some performance impact?

Comment: Role id should be in user table that this user is of this role

Comment: Totally dependent on the data you're modeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that dragging in 100 related tables to your dbcontext might not be the most performant solution and ef will drag in all tables that it can see either as a dbset, navigation property, or fluent configuration.

However if you need to navigate from roles to users in your dbcontext and the user entity has navigation properties that point to 100 of tables then your solution would be in this particular dbcontext to tell ef to ignore the tables you're not concerned with something like modelbuilder.ignore('orders') assuming from users you can navigate to orders in some way. in this way you can prune the graph to only consider the entities you need.

You then need another dbcontext for other spheres of interest: the concept is called the bounded context. (Ref Julie Lerman, Eric Evans DDD) You then need to do more work in your app to support multiple db contexts in the same app but it can be done - (See Julie Lerman on enterprise ef) However if you just want one dbcontext in your app where the scope of your model is limited to a subset of tables then the this will work.

I think you can use the ef power tools to view a read only diagram of the tables in your dbcontext model. You can then confirm how well your pruning is going.